# HibernateException: Found: clob, expected: varchar2(4000)

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat, clob, ojdbc

I have a very strange bug in my application on Tomcat 7 using Hibernate 3 and ojdbc7.jar:
In the current release, a DB column got changed to CLOB, and is configured the following way:

```
@Column(name = "BESCHREIBUNG")
@Length(min = 0, max = 4000)
@NotNull
@Lob
public String getBeschreibung() {
```

This works perfectly fine in my local environment (Oracle 11g XE) and in test environment (Oracle 12), however in prelive environment (Oracle 12), I get the following error during application start:

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Wrong column type in XXXX.MYTABLE for column BESCHREIBUNG. Found: clob, expected: varchar2(4000 char)
at org.hibernate.mapping.Table.validateColumns(Table.java:283)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.validateSchema(Configuration.java:1343) at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaValidator.validate(SchemaValidator.java:139)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:378)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1872)
at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:906)
```

Any hints on this?
I've already checked tomcat's /lib - directoryif there's an outdated ojdbc or hibernate jar, without success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the message he is still expecting a `varchar2`. As he would expect a clob if he finds a `@Lob`, I would guess that you didn't deploy the code changes to your *prelive* environment (at least not successfully).

Comment: Since I perform db migration via sql script the hdbm2dll.auto is set to validate in all environments. :/

Comment: I mixed "found" and "expected". In this case it is the other way arround (see my update).

Comment: Today, it pointed out that the error was caused by a misconfigured jdbc connection string, which was changed by one of the db admins without checking this with the dev team. As the solution was basically config/devops-related, I'll check this answer as correct.

Answer (score 12):

add column definition to solve this problem.

```
@Column(name = "entity_value", columnDefinition="clob")
```

Answer (score -2):

I just delete the `@Length(...)` and it works like a charm.